# How to prevent editing unempty cells in tstringgrid in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

[image]I have a problem and need your help
I am going to work on sudoku game. In my Stringgrid I've filled some cells with digits before [grid1.cells[8,8]:=inttostr(2); grid1.cells[2,5]:=inttostr(9); etc] and digits' text font color are black. Now I want player cannot change(edit) previous values and only able to add to  empty cells(can change only its own values). 
And values inserted into cells have to be diffent text font color(exp: clRed)
I need help in this two cases. 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: This is a nice example why separating data from UI is important. To your question, I think a good place might be an override of the `CanEditShow` method in a subclassed control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no public way to interrupt process of cell editing, but you can make a [`TStringGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid) subclass and override its [`CanEditShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomGrid.CanEditShow) protected method. In this control subclass, you can e.g. make an event to control whether the inplace editor will be created or not.

The following interposer class introduces the `OnCanEdit` event which will fire before the inplace editor is created and allows to you decide whether you want to create it or not by its `CanEdit` parameter:

```
type
  TCanEditEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Col, Row: Longint;
    var CanEdit: Boolean) of object;

  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  private
    FOnCanEdit: TCanEditEvent;
  protected
    function CanEditShow: Boolean; override;
  public
    property OnCanEdit: TCanEditEvent read FOnCanEdit write FOnCanEdit;
  end;

implementation

{ TStringGrid }

function TStringGrid.CanEditShow: Boolean;
begin
  Result := inherited CanEditShow;

  if Result and Assigned(FOnCanEdit) then
    FOnCanEdit(Self, Col, Row, Result);
end;
```

This example shows how to allow editing only for cells with row and column index greater than 2, which is not your case, but I'm sure you understand what to do:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure StringGridCanEdit(Sender: TObject; Col, Row: Longint; 
      var CanEdit: Boolean);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.OnCanEdit := StringGridCanEdit;
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGridCanEdit(Sender: TObject; Col, Row: Integer;
  var CanEdit: Boolean);
begin
  // to the CanEdit parameter assign True if you want to allow the cell
  // to be edited, False if you don't
  CanEdit := (Col > 2) and (Row > 2);
end;
```

Comment: thanks for reply but I am getting error: [expect ':' but '=' found]                 TCanEditEvent = procedure(Sender......

Comment: That part is fine. Of course I'm testing code that I post if I explicitly doesn't say otherwise. This I've tested directly in Delphi 7.

Comment: It's in my profile page, but sorry, it's Friday and I have no motivation to complete your project. What's wrong on copy pasting code from this post into your code editor ? Besides, I've intentionally answered just the first part of your question about editing, because that one is not supported by the control itself. The other part about coloring you'll find on hundreds of places over the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for all. Just getting error  [expect ':' but '=' found] after TCanEditEvent

Comment: That's weird. I can't explain why would you get this error. For being sure, [`here`](http://pastebin.com/QBjjqiC3) is shown how to merge the code from this post together (it's not clear on the first view). If even that won't help, drop me a mail.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is over 4 years old I am answering because the initial Answer is not absolutely correct. In fact there **is** a way to prevent editing specific cells:

You can set the CanSelect parameter of the TStringGrid OnSelectCell:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Options := StringGrid1.Options+[goEditing];

  StringGrid1.Cells[2,3] := '3';
  StringGrid1.Objects[2,3] := Pointer(1);
end;

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean);
begin
  if StringGrid1.Objects[ACol,ARow]<>nil then
    CanSelect := false;
end;
```

The decision to block a cell can be done by setting a blocking value to the corresponding Objects

Comment: Unfortunately this block also the possibility to select the cell/line